# C# parent/child data structure availability?

Tags: c#

is this type of data structures available in c# or as a free class library somewhere?

I want a multiple parent, multiple child type of data structure such as:

```
public class Many2ManyNode
{
    public List<Object> Parents;
    public List<Object> Children;
}
```

Its like a tree structure but with multiple parents and multiple child.

Comment: Directed graph?  Seems like you just created the desired data structure yourself, right there though.  Are you asking how to make it generic?

Comment: Any Node can be connected to any other node in a directed graph structure?

Comment: What's lacking from what you posted?

Comment: If there's not any other words you place around it, like 'acyclic' or 'simple', then I think in a directed graph any node can have any other node as its parent or child.

Comment: Whats wrong with the Many2ManyNode you have created? What purpose are you looking at it for?

Comment: I can think of one thing [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/treecollection2.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [QuickGraph library](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph) which was both compiled for silverlight and .net3.5. It also contains AI algorithms and other advance searching.

Answer (score 4):

I'll stand by my previous comments that it looks like you want a directed graph (depending on how you want to use this structure), but if you just wanted to make your code better reflect what you're asking for it would be:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Parents;
    public List<Node> Children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any data structure in the framework that does what you are after.

There is a nice MSDN post that covers implementing data structures that will give you what you want. See [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364091(VS.80).aspx)

In particular look at part 5 on graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).  Not sure if that will help or not.  Generally I've found that I could aggregate the available generic classes to build the data structures that I have needed.  Although the applications I have been working on were not overly concerned with large structures or high search performance.

Comment: I like the C5 collections but there's nothing like the OP is talking about in there.

Comment: I haven't used the collections or really looked them over to be honest.  Just googled and noticed a comment about graphs.  Last time I needed a graph the system dictated using a series of trees to describe the relationships.